# Font Awesome not working for some reason in Angular-Fullstack Yeoman Generator

Tags: css, generator, yeoman, font-awesome, angular-fullstack

I made a project using Angular-fullstack yeoman generator, so I guess my problem is quite specific to people who already used this generator. (My problem might be quite stupid as I'm still a beginner using this generator)

I can see in my bower folder that Font Awesome is there. I expect to see this linked in the index.html but it doesn't, it looks like it's in app.css instead.

From there, when I'm trying to use Font Awesome in any of my html file, it doesn't work.

If I add a linksheet in the index.html then it works but it disasppear once there is a grunt build/serve. So it's annoying and not how it should behave I guess.

I will appreciate a lot if someone can bring me some light in this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already solve this? I think you need to run `bower install` with `--save` option so that the reference to font-awesome will be in the `bower.json` and will update in index.html when you run `grunt serve`

Comment: And check the link is available to your main stylesheet when it all runs/compiles. Many times the issue is simply your site/app can't see the referenced code.

Comment: Yes its not include in my main stylesheet, and that's the problem because it should do it automatically since my bower is intalled using `--save` and font-awesome is in my bower.json  `font-awesome": ">=4.1.0"`

Comment: @Emidomh check the `bower.json` of the font-awesome folder in bower_components (there are two)...check `"main"` property...if `font-awesome.css` is not there (you'll see others like less, sass), you need to insert it.

Comment: @ElmerDantas Yes indeed `font-awesome.css` was missing in both `bower.json` in my bower_components folder, now it works perfectly ! Thanks :)